# Windows 7: How to display selected file size in the statusbar just like in WinXP?

Tags: windows-7, layout

I want to be able to select file(s) and see their total size in the statusbar, just like in WinXP, is this possible anyhow?

At the moment i can only see the count of selected files! The place where the size was displayed is empty.

**Edit:** Notice: I have disabled the "details" thing already, because i dont want to see that much information about each file, nor that huge space taken from the folder. I just need the filesize visible and selected files count (and some other info that XP Showed i cant remember correctly ATM).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Details Pane is turned off.

See the following article : [How to Turn the Details Pane On or Off in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/61507-details-pane-turn-off.html).

In a nutshell : On the toolbar, click on Organize and Layout, Select (click) Details pane to have it checked, then OK.

Comment: i disabled that for a reason already because it takes lots of space and has lots of useless information.

Comment: But among all that useless information, I believe you will find the file size.

Comment: @harrymc: yes, but when theres so much useless information, it takes _seconds_ to find the filesize when the positions always change depending on how many files you selected, and which types of files you selected! and besides, i dont want it to take that much space in one window.

Comment: Then choose one of the other many [Free File Manager](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm). My favorite is the not so new [servant salamander](http://www.altap.cz/download.html#salrel).

Comment: Seriously, that was the worst idea ever, i tried that program. It _could_ work if it replaced the explorer.exe

Comment: Well, all these programs *are* Explorer alternatives after all.